# Access a Sharepoint site from event handler

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, event-handlers

my problem is that I want to pop up a status bar in SP2010 after a File was uploaded via a single uploadform to a List.

Found this in the net: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/1730052b-d8ad-47a5-997f-23c046eb936c

Problem of all is that I do not really find a site for a description to access a Page over the event handler.

Could anyone help me pls or give me another way to do that?

Thanks for all effort!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do it from code behind instead? Like the following:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost")) 
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];

                SPEventReceiverDefinition def = list.EventReceivers.Add();

                def.Assembly = "ERDefinition, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=704f58d28567dc00";
                def.Class = "ERDefinition.ItemEvents";
                def.Name = "ItemAdded Event";
                def.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
                def.SequenceNumber = 1000;
                def.Synchronization = SPEventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
                def.Update();
            }
        }
```

Reference: [Binding an Event Handler by Using the SharePoint Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407249%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

---

Edit:

Maybe you can try parts of this script, where you access a list via jQuery?

[image: jQuery client list access]

Reference: [SharePoint list access – Part III – How to access SharePoint Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) REST (Representational State Transfer) services using jQuery (entirely client side only).](http://mydevexperience.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/sharepoint-list-access-part-iii-how-to-access-sharepoint-windows-communication-foundation-wcf-rest-representational-state-transfer-services-using-jquery-entirely-client-side-only/)

Comment: Maybe but I dont know really how. Normally I write scripts so is it possible to those stuff over ECMA script?

Comment: @FelixZeidler I've edited the answer, hope it's useful!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but at this time I don´t get the breakthrough